# Search string in file if found add four lines above in PHP

Tags: php, file

I want to add four line of code in a PHP file if it found for string 'test' in the file anywhere. I google a lot on this, but didn't get exact solution :( 
Please  help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?  Show us your sample data, your expected results, and the code you've written so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can search your text in file like this:

```
$data = file_get_contents('file.ext');

if(strpos($data, 'text') !== FALSE)
{
    $file_data = "Stuff you want to add\n";
    $file_data .= $data;
    file_put_contents('file.ext', $file_data);
}
```

For appending lines at the end of the file use

```
file_put_contents('file.ext', $text_to_append, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

FILE_APPEND flag is for appending at the end of file and LOCK_EX flag to prevent anyone else writing to the file at the same time

Comment: What shall I use fwrite or file_put_contents in the if condition so that it should not overwrite the file but append four lines above it.

Comment: I have edited my answer to search text and append string if it finds.

Comment: It's adding lines to beginnning of the file :(

Comment: You said you need to add lines above it. Anyway I have edited my answer again and added code for appending lines at the end of file.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. Let me elaborate on that, I want to add those lines in the middle of file and above that search string. But the code adds either starting of file or ending. Many Thanks for your reply.